# How to prove maxSpec $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ as topological spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am new to algebraic geometry, and am reading the book *An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry*.  Exercise 2.6.4 in this book asks you to prove the topological space $\displaystyle\operatorname{maxSpec}\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x^2)}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$. Can anyone show me how to prove?

Intuitively I think $\mathbb{A}^1$ should be homeomorphic to $\displaystyle\operatorname{maxSpec }\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x)}$ which is maxSpec $\mathbb{C}[x]$, and is different from  $\displaystyle\operatorname{maxSpec}\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x^2)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximal ideals of ${\mathbb C}[x,y]$ containing $(x^2)$ are the same ideals as the maximal ideals of ${\mathbb C}[x,y]$ containing $(x)$.

After that, as you mention in the question, use that ${\mathbb A}^1$ is (homeomorphic to) $\text{maxSpec } {\mathbb C}[x]$.

Comment: Thanks! And therefore maxSpec $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$ and maxSpec $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x)$ are the exactly the same, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. (Well, they're canonically isomorphic, as maximal ideals of ${\mathbb C}[x,y]/(x^2)$ correspond to maximal ideals of ${\mathbb C}[x,y]$ containing $(x^2)$, which are the maximal ideals of ${\mathbb C}[x,y]$ containing $(x)$, which correspond to the maximal ideals of ${\mathbb C}[x,y]/(x)$.

Comment: This is a good example to keep in mind when, in a few weeks, you learn that given an arbitrary ideal $I\subset A$ in a ring you have a dual  closed immersion $\operatorname {Spec}\frac {A}{\sqrt I}\hookrightarrow \operatorname {Spec}\frac {A}{I}$ which is not an isomorphism if $I\subsetneq \sqrt I$ , but is always a homeomorphism.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Good point, but with some luck the OP reached this point about 8 years ago already.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Haha, yes, you are right: I hadn't looked at the date!