# Let $R= \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$. Show that $\operatorname{maxSpec}R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $R= \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$. Show that $\operatorname{maxSpec}R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$. This example illustrates the idea behind a scheme. We ought to think of $\operatorname{maxSpec} R$ as the $y$-axis $V(x^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ "counted twice" since it is defined by $x^2$ instead of the radical ideal generated by $x$.

I don't really get what they mean by this

> We ought to think of $\operatorname{maxSpec} R$ as the $y$-axis $V(x^2) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ "counted twice" since it is defined by $x^2$ instead of the radical ideal generated by $x$.

statement. What I have is a bijective correspondence between the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$ and the ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ containing $(x^2)$, but I don't know how I can get to argue anything related to the homeomorphism. I should find a continuous bijection with continuous inverse to conclude the homeomorphism. Where should I start the problem?

Comment: What is $n?{}{}$

Comment: It should be $2$ in the description and $1$ in the title.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: The first place to start is to identify the topology on these spaces. It's particularly simple, and your bijection can easily be upgraded to a homeomorphism. (Separately, did you check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765128/how-to-prove-maxspec-mathbbcx-y-x2-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbba1-a?rq=1)) with almost the same title?)

Comment: I think it's the Zariski topology? I did check out the question, but I'm looking more at the intutition on how we can "visualize" $\operatorname{maxSpec}R$ as for me it's purely an algebraic object and I wonder what do they mean by counting twice the $y$-axis.

Comment: Is the intuition to think about $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$ as the coordinate ring $\Bbb C[V]$, where $V = \Bbb V(x^2)$ and so we have a correspondence between points of $V$ and the maximal ideals of $\Bbb C[V]$?

Comment: Yes, it is the Zariski topology, but in this case it has a particularly simple description by some words you might have already seen in a topology class. What are the closed sets in each? Next, for visualization, nilpotents like this are often visualized as a thickened version of whatever you're thinking about. Finally, you may want to check out [@ replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), since I didn't get any notification of your messages and only saw them by luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly pointed out that the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$
are the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ that contain $(x^2)$. Now, the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are of the form $(x-a,y-b)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2)$ are $(x,y-b)$. These are clearly in bijection with the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[y]$. This defines the map, which you now have to show is a homeomorhpism.